# Phonegap: How to navigate device file directory

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm just looking for something similar as the behaviour of the `<input type="file" />` feature but I am getting no luck.

I have tried the `fileSystem` and `inAppBrowser` but it looks like that behaviour it's not inside those API.

Any help?

UPDATE: This is the code I've being using to search in file directory

```
var onDeviceReady = (function () {
    alert('device ready');
    var button = document.getElementById('loadbutton');
    button.addEventListener('touchstart', function () {
         window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, fail);

         function onSuccess(fileSystem) {
             alert(fileSystem.name);
             alert(fileSystem.root.name);
         }

         function fail(error){
             alert('File System Error: ' + error.code);
         }

    }, false);
}());
```

Comment: how you do that? codes?

Comment: I have updated the code using the Phonegap File API but it doesn't work. I just got the onSuccess function but I was never allowed to chose a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
var onDeviceReady = (function () {
    alert('device ready');
    var button = document.getElementById('loadbutton');
    button.addEventListener('touchstart', function () {
         window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, fail);
 function onSuccess(fileSystem) {
             fileSystem.root.getDirectory("DO_NOT_DELETE", {
                create: true,
                exclusive: false
            }, gotDirEntry, fail);
         }

         function fail(error){
             alert('File System Error: ' + error.code);
         }
        function gotDirEntry(dirEntry) {
            dirEntry.getFile("sample.json", {create: true, exclusive: false},gotfile, fail);
        }
function gotfile(fileentry){
console.log("file ");
}

    }, false);
}());
```